# Gas wall heater issues

Tags: walls, gas, heater

Why does my gas wall heater turn on and off intermittently when the switch is off?
It's NOT the fan turning on and off
Its the flames coming on then quickly going out!   Why? and thank you!

Comment: What make and model is this heater?

Comment: It's a HouseWarmer.      Gravity vented single wall furnace.    HW350GW0XX1(N,P)-3 series...

Comment: It's by EmpireComfortSystems Inc.